# how to fast load the jquery nicescroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery nicescroll (http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) in may web page that using ajax tabbing jquery.

I have the main.php page that calls the news.html to load.

main.php

```
<nav>
<ul>
...
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
...
</nav>
<section id="cont1">
...
</section>
<section id="cont2" style="display:none">
</section>
```

ajax-load.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li a").click(function() {
;
    $("section#cont2").fadeIn(200).siblings().hide();
        $("ul li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
            $("section#cont2").empty().append(html);

            }
        });
    return false;
    });
```

news.html css

```
#content-scroll{
    height:500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

this my news.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#content-scroll").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#000",background:"#ccc",autohidemode:false});
  });

</script>

<div id="content-scroll">
 .... long text ....
</div>
```

My problem now is that in the live, when I call the news.html, the default scroll will shows up first then later on the jquery nicescroll.

the demo did not shows the default scroll, I think it is because of the ajax tabbing jquery.

Is there any way that the default scroll will not shows up, instead the jquery nicescroll will be loaded fast?

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you load that default scroll AFTER the jQuery call?